# Create kivy widgets accelerator

Tags: python, kivy

i m new on kivy now i use it to create android apps, when creating widgets by coding it in kv language or python on computer need to create code and run code then change in some positions or sizes and run it again and finally when convert it to apk don't match well the smart phone screen and the cycle restart.
So is there any tool to create Widgets using drag and drop in kv language, like android studio or visual studio.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the GUI on your PC instead of uploading your apk every time.

What you need is running your mobile app on your PC using these arguments [(read docs here)](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.screen.html): `python main.py -m screen:note2,portrait,scale=.75`

Remember to use `dp` or `sp` metrics in your entire app. If you use the default `px` somewhere, the GUI will look different.

Comment: thx that is really helpful  :)

Comment: @omarbouzoumita Please mark the answer as accepted if it is sufficient.